# How do I manage groups/rooms with node WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, web-services, sockets, express, websocket

*TL;DR* below.

I am currently developing a React/Redux SPA that is driven by real-time data. I've decided to use `ws`, instead of `socket.io` since `socket.io` feels a bit high level for what I'm doing, I'd rather manage sockets myself.

In saying that, I'm struggling to find a way to manage the separation of updates/messages per view/route. Since I'm using client-side routing it's per express route won't really work...

Messages between the server and client via WebSockets are JSON with actions like `GET_ITEMS` then a response of `GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS` with an array of 'items' and for errors: `..._ERROR` etc. This is all fine, since it's just 1 to 1 transaction. Though the problem arises when broadcasting (1 to all) to all relevant clients when the server receives an update.

So, I assume it best practice to limit these broadcasts to the clients that are viewing/want the data. So when viewing, for example, the `Item` page, there is no point in broadcasting updates to the `User` data since that is only used on the `User` page.

I haven't been able to find any common practices when dealing with this sort of situation, just a few small outdated/barely used wrappers for `ws` that just add a few basic functions to leave/join but don't offer much flexibility with implementation.

What I think *MIGHT* work is to have an object/array for each 'group'/'room', which stores the clients that are currently listening to updates from a given section. So a user would send an action to `INIT_LISTEN` (& ``) with a param of category, e.g. `ITEM` for updates and other actions related to items.

---

*TL;DR*

**What my question really boils down to is: How do I store a reference to a single socket? (`ws` client object? `ws` client ID?)** Then, can I store this in an object/array to iterate through like below.

```
 const ClientRooms = {
      Items: {
           {
                ...ws
           }
           /* ...rest of the client */
      }
 }
```

or

```
 const ClientRooms = {
      Items: [ "xyz" ] /* Array of ws ids */
 }
```

I have a "ping--pong" heartbeat function to keep clients active and prevent silent connection failures/disconnections. I can't find if `ws.terminate()` still fires the ws `close` event so I can iterate 'group'/'room' the object/array to find and remove instances of that client.